# How to farm coloured shard?

Tags: theatrhythm-curtain-call

I began Theatrhythm Final Fantasy: Curtain Call a few days ago, and have only a handfull of character. I do not have a sufficient level to farm other Chaos Quest but the first one.

The only times I ve unlocked coloured shard was when going beyond a multiple of 250 rythmia, where I get to enought shard of one colour to unlock a character instantly, and one shard from the first chaos quest.

Since rythmia not give only shard, where can I get more? Should I farm Chaos Quest short 1 until I can do the other? Or should I just farm rythmia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, at about 10k or 12k rm the rewards will drop to being for only every 500rm earned, and you'll only get one shard at a time rather than a set. This makes farming rm for shards really ineffective.

Chaos Quests are, so far as I've found, the only other source for shards. Don't pay too much attention to the levels, it's just an indication of whether to expect easy, medium or hard versions of the score.

The longer quests have slightly greater rewards, and remember that you just have to manage to clear each stage, then you can use potions, etc. if you're having difficulty.

Comment: As of how was written the tutorial, it seems if I don t kill the boss in the last stage, the quest is not considered complete => no reward. I do get shard even if I fail the quest ?

Comment: Well, yes... but how many times do you clear a battle stage without killing at least one of the enemies? Are you equipping your party's abilities as they unlock?

Comment: Never, but the boss may be the second, third, or sometime fourth monster to appear. As for now, I always beat it, but with a party ranging from 23 to 11, I m not quite sure a quest lvl25 is recommended.

Comment: I did a level 30 quest with characters in the late teens, and noticed no difference.

Comment: That s good to know : )